# How to multiply N vectors by N matrices using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a matrix `M` of shape `(N, L)` and a 3D tensor `P` of shape `(N, L, K)`. I want to get  matrix `V` of shape `(N, K)` where `V[i] = M[i] @ P[i]`. I can do it with for loop but that's inefficient, I want to do it with a single or few operations so that it would run in parallel on CUDA.

I tried just multiplying it like so

```
V = M @ P
```

but that results in a 3D tensor where `V[i, j] = M[j] @ P[i]`.

`np.diagonal(M @ P).T` is basically what I want, but calculating it like that wastes a lot of computation.

Comment: `np.squeeze(M[:,None]@P)` should treat the  1st dim as batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> M = np.random.rand(5, 2)
>>> P = np.random.rand(5, 2, 3)

>>> V = np.einsum('nl,nlk->nk', M, P)

>>> V.shape
(5, 3)
```